# Change individual listbox item font in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I want to change the property of just a single item in a list box. I currently have the user select an item from the list box, which is then passed as a parameter for processing. I want to be able to either remove the item form the list, or, even better, change the font so they can see which items have to be processed, and which have already been completed.

I have the following code:

```
Sub updateLaunchScreen_CrossDayOff()

Dim i As Long

     With ReadingsLauncher

        With .dayListBox
            For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
                If .Selected(i) Then
                    .Font.Strikethrough = True
                End If
            Next i
        End With

    End With

End Sub
```

However this changes every item in the list.

I have googled the issue but havent been able to find anything specifically relating to changing the property of a single list item in a list box.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to be able to either remove the item form the list

If you want to delete the item then I would suggest this

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If ListBox1.ListIndex > -1 Then
        ListBox1.RemoveItem (ListBox1.ListIndex)
    End If
End Sub
```

> or, even better, change the font so they can see which items have to be processed, and which have already been completed.

If you want to see which items have been processed then you can use this option.

Make your Listbox a MultiSelect listbox with Checkbox options. See Snapshot

[image]

To get this type of listbox you can either set the properties in design time or at run time. For example

**DESIGN TIME**

[image]

**RUN TIME**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With ListBox1
        .MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectMulti
        .ListStyle = fmListStyleOption
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Works Excellently. Thankyou very much. Out of curiosity, when multiple items are selected, how would i get the last item the user selected. I currently loop through the items from top to bottom. This works because that is the order the user should be operating in, however may not work in some of my other project (e.g. sort order and process order different)

Comment: every time a user selects an entry, store the listindex in a variable :)

Comment: Siddharth Rout: You are a supreme fellow. You deserve nice things! Many thanks!